# divs floated to left and right + another div therebetween

Tags: css, html

This is my mockup:

[image: divs]

I want to set divs as in the picture. DIV 1 and DIV 2 contain dynamically generated content and the width is different every time.

Div 1 is floated to the left side and Div 2 is floated to the right side.

My question is: how to position Div 3 to fit it between div 1 and 3?

My code is:
HTML

```
<div class="dia">
 <div class="left">sassssss</div>
 <div class="center">dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd</div>
 <div class="right">asdasdfgdsgdf</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.dia {
background: #282828;
padding: 10px;
height: 106px;
border-radius: 5px;
}

.dia .center {
 margin-left: 20px;
}


.dia .left, .dia .right {
 overflow: hidden;
}

.dia .left {
 float: left;
 margin-right: 10px;
}

.dia .right {
 float: right;
 margin-left: 10px;
 background: rgb(214,214,214);
}
```

and I want to fit center div which now is too wide and moves right div lower than I want.

**SOLUTION:**

HTML

```
<div class="dia">
 <div class="left">sassssss</div>
 <div class="center">ddddddddddddddddddddd dddddddddddddddddddddddddd ddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd dddddddddddd</div>
 <div class="right">asdasdfgdsgdf</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.dia {
 background: #282828;
 padding: 10px;
 height: 106px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 width: inherit;
}

.dia .left, .dia .right {
 overflow: hidden;
 height: 106px;
}

.dia .left {
 float: left;
 margin-right: 10px;
}

.dia .right {
 float: right;
 margin-left: 10px;
}

.dia .center {
 height: inherit;
 float: left;
}
```

JQuery

```
$('.dia .left a:not(:first-child)').css('width',$('.dia a').outerWidth(true)+'px'); 
$('.dia .center').css('width',$('.dia').width()-$('.dia .left').outerWidth(true)-$('.dia .right').outerWidth(true)+'px');
```

And [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/natanielcz/sFgRx/)

Comment: Please add your code to the question as well, that way if the [link rots](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot) this question will remain useful to future visitors.

Comment: Do you know how wide div 1 and 2 are as you generate the page?

Comment: Setting a fixed width to your `.dia` / parent class can resolve your issue.

Comment: Jeroen: I add it in few minutes.
Laurence: No. I don't know.
Shahar: I'll try it tomorrow. ;)

Comment: Shahar: I setted fixed width but it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I did manage to do this in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2bcAd/), but it feels a little like a workaround, since you have to be careful with center content. Then again, it works, so you can use it as a placeholder or something until you or someone else comes up with better solution.

CSS:

```
.dia {
background: #282828;
padding: 10px;
height: 106px;
border-radius: 5px;
}

.dia .center {
overflow:auto;
height: 100px;
background-color: #aaa;
margin-left: 20px;
}

.dia .left {
float: left;
height: 100px;
background-color: #ddd;
}

.dia .right {
position:absolute;
/*.dia padding + border*/
right: 15px;
/*.dia padding + border + (.dia height - this height)/2*/
top: 18px;
height: 100px;
background: rgb(214,214,214);
}
```

Comment: so. to this fiddle i have to add only line breaking ;)

Comment: It depends on what you are using your side divs for. If they don't have much content, this shouldn't be a problem. But I think the answer and comments by raam86 sound better.

Comment: I get it to work tomorrow. ;) It's probably the best solution for my idea :)

Comment: In yours solution center div was to wide and text isn't displayed completely but setting static height is a good idea ;) Thanks for help (I can't set your post as useful because 15 rep is required)

Comment: @Maciej Czekaj wait, you mean you can't select an answer? You should see a black&white "check" symbol under the votes number... Click it to accept an answer.

Comment: But nobody published 100% correct answer. Everyone help me in which direction I have to go but in every answer requires something more than it's written. So I want to mark answer as useful not as a correct.

Answer (score 2):

Simply float the central div.

For your purpose you case use:

```
.dia{
float:left//Float container in order to contain nested elements.
}

.dia div{
float:left;
}
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/raam86/YvnnW/10/) you can fiddle with

Comment: but when parent div will be not enough wide three divs will be one below another. Try resize Result area to smaller width one and you'll see. I want something like on my mockup.

Comment: You can add a min-width property to avoid that. It all depends in the content. like this http://jsfiddle.net/raam86/YvnnW/28/

Comment: but i don't know the min width required for content in div 1 and 2. It'll have dynamic size content.

Comment: So use javascript. You can't have it all

Comment: but maybe i can calculate secure width for side divs.. Thanks ;)
so.. JavaScript can help me. Right. I want to mark your answer as useful but i haven't reputation enough. How can i get some?

Comment: You can click the the tick under the vote count. This will choose the answer. You can also give useful answers for more rep ;)

Comment: I need 15 rep points to mark as useful but i have only 11 :( :P

Comment: You need 15 rep to vpvote and no minimum rep to choose best answer/

Comment: But nobody published 100% correct answer. Everyone help me in which direction I have to go but in every answer requires something more than it's written. So I want to mark answer as useful not as a correct.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
#main 
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: -webkit-flex; /* Safari */
    display: flex;
}

#panelLeft, #panelRight
{
    -webkit-flex: 1;  /* Safari 6.1+ */
    -ms-flex: 1;  /* IE 10 */    
    flex: 1;
}

#panelCenter
{
    -webkit-flex: 3;  /* Safari 6.1+ */
    -ms-flex: 3;  /* IE 10 */    
    flex: 3;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="main">
  <div id="panelLeft" style="background-color:coral;">RED</div>
  <div id="panelCenter" style="background-color:lightblue;">BLUE</div>  
  <div id="panelRight" style="background-color:lightgreen;">Green div with more content.</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

How about using a table instead?

```
<table class="dia">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
             <td class="left">sassssss</td>
             <td class="center">dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd</td>
             <td class="right">asdasdfgdsgdf</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Then the CSS would be:

```
.dia {
    background: #282828;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 106px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
}

.dia .center {
    margin-left: 20px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}


.dia .left, .dia .right {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.dia .left {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.dia .right {
    float: right;
    margin-left: 10px;
    background: rgb(214,214,214);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YvnnW/13/

Comment: I would agree in most cases. Makes this problem easily fixed though.

Comment: Seeing HTML is semantic and OP doesn't state it is probably better to use divs or sections or anythings which isn't table which bloats the page and is inflexible.

Comment: Tables are used to hold tabular data. Why people decide to keep on using them for layout is beyond me. Every browser renders them differently. So even if it may seem easier to do it with tables, in the end some of your users will pay the price.

Comment: I'm rewriting page from tables so I can't use your solve (but your fiddle shows what i want to do) ;)

Comment: Dunno's idea works. as long as you also add `word-break: break-word;` to your divs so that those super long words will be forced to wrap.