# How do i make an embedded youtube video shrink with the page when I have a nav bar being floated left, and a nav bar being floated right

Tags: html, css, youtube, css-float

I am currently making a page on my site in which I have put a nav bar(float: right) and a nav bar(float:left), but whenever I try to embed a youtube video, the right nav bar ends up at the bottom of the page. Does anyone know what css code I can use to fix this problem? This is what I currently have:
Html:

```
<div class="video-wrapper"> 
<iframe width="700" height="525" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/MYN5aBPmpZE?rel=0"     frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Css:

```
    .videoWrapper {
position: relative;
padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16:9 */
padding-top: 25px;
height: 0;
}
.videoWrapper iframe {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: [this][1] discussion should help you.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18282318/divs-floated-to-left-and-right-another-div-therebetween

Answer (score 0):

James
First and foremost, the question is a little ambiguous, since you stated that nav bar {float:left} and the same nav bar is floated again right. However I am assuming they are different nav bars. But if they are the same then there is a problem with that concept.

Check your code, the css code has a class named videoWrapper but you assigned video-wrapper to the youtube video iframe. Since, this video-wrapper is not defined in the css file, the browser renders it in the default flowlayout. Try changing the the class name to make them consistent.

Comment: I actually ended up adding the code iframe{0 right-floated-width 0 left-floated-width;}